# jQuery ScrollTop+fade transition between pages

Tags: jquery, transition, fade, scrolltop

I'm trying to set up a transition between the pages of my website, like this: http://emilolsson.com/hi-response/ (click on 'view example' into '3 modules generator' section).

So this is a mix of Animate's scrolltop and fade.

Here's my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#content').css({opacity: 0});

  $('#content').fadeTo(250, 1);

  $('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $('#content').fadeTo(250, 0, function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      }, 500, redirectPage);
    });
  });

  function redirectPage() {
    window.location = linkLocation;
  }
});
```

My HTML markup looks like this:

```
<div id="header" style="position: fixed;">
  <a href="newpage.php">Link</a> 
</div>
<div id="content">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

And as you can see I try to get this effect pecking order:

- the content fadeIn at the page load
- when you click a link, the content fadeOut
- then the window scrolltop
- finally we're getting the new page
- the content fadeIn at the page load

But I encounter a few issues:
- the content of the new page quickly appear before the transition so it flicks
- the scrolltop transition is too quick when you click on a link to the bottom of the page

Any idea to improve my code?

Thank you much!

Comment: The flash occurs because your code doesn't fire until the DOM is ready. You _could_ set the opacity to 0 in the CSS, that way it would be hidden from the start. However, the better way to do it would be to use ajax to load the content, and use the HTML5 History API to change the URL/state. If you take a look at the demo you provided, that's exactly how they do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I had not managed to see how the demo works, so thank you for bringing me this answer.

Now I think I have to find a solution to vary the animation speed depending on the offset.top position of the link the user just clicked on.